# trying to get value to only show when its less than 100

Tags: sql

Im trying to get PRO.process_total_estimate to only show then its less than 100

do i need a case statement?

```
SELECT
        PRO.process_no AS 'JOB', 
        PRO.process_name AS 'NAME',  
        CONCAT(CHAR(39), PRO.process_total_estimate) AS 'ESTIMATE' 
    FROM 
        PROCESS PRO
        JOIN PROCESS_TYPE PJT ON PJT.process_type_id = PRO.process_type_id
        AND PRO.process_total_estimate = > 100

    ORDER BY
        PRO.process_date_et_start
```

Comment: You would use `<=` rather than `>=`.

Comment: So why do you have this line of code: `AND PRO.process_total_estimate = > 100` and you say this: "Im trying to get PRO.process_total_estimate to only show then its less than 100"

Comment: the first comment was the correct one, i was just stupid. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need simple WHERE I guess?

```
SELECT
        PRO.process_no AS 'JOB', 
        PRO.process_name AS 'NAME',  
        CONCAT(CHAR(39), PRO.process_total_estimate) AS 'ESTIMATE' 
    FROM 
        PROCESS PRO
        JOIN PROCESS_TYPE PJT ON PJT.process_type_id = PRO.process_type_id
    WHERE PRO.process_total_estimate <= 100

ORDER BY
    PRO.process_date_et_start
```